# M101P: Taking this course, I am getting this error when I run this file. Any suggestions?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[image]

I am taking this course from Mongodb University. I have posted on their discussion board but have been unsuccessful. Unfortunately, to subsequent lectures are all based on read_reddit.py running. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

THE CODE FOR "read_reddit.py" IS BELOW:

```
import json
import urllib2
import pymongo

# connect to mongo
connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")

# get a handle to the reddit database
db = connection.reddit
stories = db.stories

# drop existing collection
stories.drop()

# get the reddit home page
reddit_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/.json")

# parse the json into python objects
parsed = json.loads(reddit_page.read())

# iterate through every news item on the page
for item in parsed['data']['children']:
    # put it in mongo
    stories.insert_one(item['data'])
```

Comment: You need to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` that comes with the folder to install all your dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the python libraries you're using in your script. Run the following commands in your terminal:

```
pip install urllib2
pip install pymongo
```